# Cant's add custom product attribute for sorting

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configuration, install-script

I'm trying to add a custom product attribute called `popularity` a decimal so I can use it for sorting products on the catalog pages.

I've created a module for this and while I can see the module is installed in *System > Config > Advanced* their is no record of the table in the `core_resource` table.

I have tried clearing the cache & re-indexing.

**app/etc/modules/Namespace_PopularityAttribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/PopularityAttribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <popularityattribute>
        <class>Namespace_PopularityAttribute_Helper</class>
      </popularityattribute>
      <resources>
        <popularityattribute_setup>
          <setup>
            <module>PopularityAttribute</module>
            <class>PopularityAttribute_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
          </setup>
          <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
          </connection>
        </popularityattribute_setup>
        <popularityattribute_write>
          <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
          </connection>
        </popularityattribute_write>
        <popularityattribute_read>
          <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
          </connection>
        </popularityattribute_read>
      </resources>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/PopularityAttribute/sql/popularityattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'popularity', array(
    'group'         => 'Our Custom Group',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'decimal',
    'label'         => 'Popularity',
    'note' => 'Will be used as the default method of sorting products on the category pages in descending order.',
    'default' => true,
    'default_value' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 2,
    'visible'       => false,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable'    => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'  => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**app/etc/modules/Namespace_PopularityAttribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
     </Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/PopularityAttribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_PopularityAttribute>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <resources>
            <popularityattribute_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_PopularityAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </popularityattribute_setup>
     </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/PopularityAttribute/sql/popularityattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'popularity', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'decimal',
    'label'         => 'Popularity',
    'default'           => true,
    'default_value'     => 0,
    'sort_order'        => 2,
    'visible'           => false,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'      => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'=> false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front'  => false,
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'used_in_product_listing'   => true,
    'note'          => 'Will be used as the default method of sorting products on the category pages in descending order.',

));
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Note:** clearing the cache & re-indexing.

Comment: this doesn't actually add the popularity attribute properly.  I can't see it on the admin panel, on manage products or manage attributes pages

Comment: I can see the module version in `core_resource` and the attribute in the `eav_attribute` tables but it is not showing up on the manage product / attribute pages

Comment: Updated ans pls check now